# MySQL: Group By & Count Multiple Fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I have a single field, say, project_id where I want to count the occurrences, I would do something like:

```
select project_id, count(project_id) as count from tbl group by project_id, order by count desc
```

What if I want to count the occurrences of a combination of two fields in the same table, i.e. count the number of rows where the combination of project_id and service_id are unique?

So, so I have records in my table like:

```
project_id   service_id
1            1
1            2
1            2
1            2
1            2
1            3
1            4
1            4
1            4


I would want the result of my query to be something like:

project_id   service_id   count
1            1            1
1            2            4
1            3            1
1            4            3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select project_id, service_id, count(*) as count 
from tbl group by project_id, service_id
order by count(*) desc
```

Just add `service_id` to your `group by` and `select` list. That should do it.

**EDIT -**

As per comment from `@Rajah` it seems that for your expected output, you need to use

```
order by project_id asc, service_id asc
```

Comment: Yep! So simple, I should have been able to get that on my own. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for a good answer, @Sachin Shanbhag. Do you think that the order by clause might look more like David's desired result with *order by project_id, service_id asc*

Comment: @David - It would've taken you less time than framing this question I suppose.. Anyway you are welcome. ;)

Comment: @rajah - Correct, you are right and you are saying that due to the expected output added by David. Adding your suggestion to my answer as well. Thank you very much.