# MySQL: Group By multiple fields and count

Tags: mysql

This type of question is answered in post "[MySQL: Group By & Count Multiple Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5328987/2968762)"

**EDIT : Sample Query Used**

SELECT actors.id AS actor_id, actors.act_name AS actor_name, details.registration_id AS
 registration from games INNER JOIN actors ON actors.id = games.actor_id INNER JOIN
details ON details.id = games.detail_id WHERE 'some cond' GROUP BY registration, actor_id;

But, I'm unable to achieve it in my case. My table data is little different (I'm grouping the table by registration, actor_id). eg:

```
actor_id | actor_name     | registration
----------------------------------------
189      | ABC            | 1234-1234
189      | ABC            | 4567-1234
189      | ABC            | 7890-4321
169      | DEF            | 1111-5643
169      | DEF            | 1111-5643
```

and I expect the output as below

```
actor_id | actor_name     | registration | actor_count
------------------------------------------------------
189      | ABC            | 1234-1234    | 3
189      | ABC            | 4567-1234    | 3
189      | ABC            | 7890-4321    | 3
169      | DEF            | 1111-5643    | 2
169      | DEF            | 1111-5643    | 2
```

That is actor ABC has 3 occurrences in table and DEF has 2 occurrences, etc
Instead when I use count(*) I get an expected count of 1 in each row
But, Is there a way to achieve the above output?

Comment: You don't need to group by multiple fields. You just want to group by the `actor_id` and get the count. Then you join that with the original table to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by doing a sub query to the same table. Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    actors.actor_id,
    actors.actor_name,
    actors.registration,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            actors AS innerActors
        WHERE innerActors.actor_id=innerActors.actor_id
    ) AS actor_count
FROM
    actors
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive your goal by joining your base table to an aggregation subquery (in mysql).

For example:

```
SELECT
  A.actor_id, A.actor_name, A.registration, B.actor_count
FROM
  YourTable AS A
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      actor_id, COUNT(1) AS actor_count
    FROM
      YourTable
    GROUP BY
      actor_id
  ) B
    ON A.actor_id = B.actor_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a subquery that gets the count for each actor. Then join this with the original table to put the count on each of their rows.

```
SELECT t1.actor_id, t1.actor_name, t1.registration, t2.actor_count
FROM YourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT actor_id, COUNT(*) AS actor_count
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY actor_id) AS t2 ON t1.actor_id = t2.actor_id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e9117/1)

If you include `registration` in the grouping, you'll get counts of `1` because the registration is different on each row.

Comment: Actually that is the problem, I can't exclude registration as I need to show the actor with different registrations. Also I'm facing hard time to implement this with MYSQL as the output above is achieved by lots of joins with other tables.

Comment: I never said to exclude it from the output, I said to exclude it from the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That's why you need a subquery. You need to count by actor separately from outputting the result table.

Comment: Thanks for the DEMO fiddle, but the query works for me if "YourTable" is a separate table, but in my case its a long query, so if I do select * from (SELECT ....) AS t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT actor_id, COUNT(*) AS actor_count FROM t1)..... It can't find table t1

Comment: Please post the actual conditions in the question if you want something that works with it.