# Count data and eliminating duplication in SQL (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have data in this table.

[image]
.....
....

so i want the output to look like table
[image]

what is the SQL for that?

Comment: Look up for `Count` aggregate and `Group by` clause

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Group By & Count Multiple Fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328987/mysql-group-by-count-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 3):

Simple. `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`.

```
select
    customer_no,
    items,
    count(*) "COUNT"
from your_table
group by customer_no,
    items;
```